# What is the difference between average of journal first decision and submission to first post-review decision?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, journal-workflow

I noticed that in Taylor and Francis metrics there are two concepts:

Average submission to first decision

and

Average submission to first post-review decision

Could any one demonstrate the difference, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A desk reject would be a "first decision", but not a "first post-review decision". I would thus assume that the first number includes desk rejects, and the second number is taking the average only for those submissions that do get sent out for review.